# Why do I have the option to *not* call Concurrency::agent::done inside run?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, concurrency, concurrency-runtime, concrt

This is in the context of the Microsoft C++ Concurrency API.

There's a class called `agent` (under `Concurrency` namespace), and it's basically a state machine you derive and implement pure virtual `agent::run`.

Now, it is your responsibility to call `agent::start`, which will put it in a *runnable* state. You then call `agent::wait`*, or any of its variants, to actually execute the `agent::run` method.

But why do we have to call `agent::done` within the body? I mean, the obvious answer is that `agent::wait`* will wait until done is signaled or the timeout has elapsed, but...

What were the designers intending? Why not have the agent enter the done state when `agent::run` returns? That's what I want to know. Why do I have the option to not call `done`? The wait methods throw exceptions if the timeout has elapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the only reason I can see is that it would let you state you are `done()`, then do more work (say, cleanup) that you don't want your consumer to have to wait on.

Now, they could have done this:

```
private: void agent::do_run() {
  run();
  if (status() != agent_done)
    done();
}
```

then have their framework call `do_run()` instead of `run()` directly (or the equivalent).

However, you'll note that you yourself can do this.

```
class myagent: public agent {
protected:
  virtual void run() final override { /* see do_run above, except call do_run in it */ }
  virtual void do_run() = 0;
};
```

and poof, if your `do_run()` fails to call `done()`, the wrapping function does it for you.  If this second virtual function overhead is too high for you:

```
template<typename T>
class myagent: public agent {
private:
  void call_do_run()
  {
    static_cast<T*>(this)->do_run();
  }
protected:

  virtual void run() final override { /* see do_run above, but call_do_run() */ }
};
```

the CRTP that lets you do compile-time dispatch.  Use:

```
class foo: public myagent<foo>
{
public:
  void do_run() { /* code */ }
};
```

... /shrug

Comment: Your first comment, signaling doneness without making the consumer wait, IS BRILLIANT. I never would have thought of that. Wow, the possibilities...

Thanks, that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.